# Dynamic Array and function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to do my project and I am stuck. My professor wants me to use a dynamic array if I understood, and a function to compare integer numbers and get their GCD. I cant make the function work. Any thoughts?
Here is the prom:

Write a a program to calculate the greatest common divisor of any finite set of integers. Use a function to calculate the GCD. The number of elements in the set should not be predetermined.You need to write the code that will count, as you enter the data,how many numbers are in the set. Base in the Euclid's algorithm or so.

I input 10, 100 and 40 and GCD should be 10;however,I get this results:

```
The GCD of:  is: 
   10         0    
  100         0
   40         0
```

> 

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int greatestdivisor(int b[], int size); /*Write prototype for gcd */

int main()
{
    int greatest;
    int max=1;
    int* a= new int[max]; //allocated on heap
    int n=0;

    cout<<"Input numbers: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Hit Enter key after each input and type any letter to finish"<<endl;

    while(cin>>a[n]){     //read into array
        n++;
        if(n>=max){
            max=n;   //increase size of array
            int* temp = new int[max];    //creates new bigger array

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                temp[i] = a[i];   //copy values to new array
            } //end for
            delete [] a;     //free old array memory
            a = temp;     //a points to new array
        } //end if

    } // end while
    cout<<endl;
    greatest = greatestdivisor(a, max);
    cout<<"The GCD of: "<<" is: "<<endl;
    for(int j=0;j<max;j++)
        cout<<setw(5)<<a[j]<<setw(10)<<greatest<<endl;
    n++;// prints elements of array and call function
} // end main

// gcd finds greatest common divisor of array
int greatestdivisor(int b[], int size)
{
    int greatest =1;// current greatest common divisor, 1 is minimum

    for (int x=0; x<=size; x++) {
        int m=b[x];
        int r=2;
        if(m%r==0){
            greatest =m; // update greatest common divisor
        } //end if
    } // end for
    return greatest; //return gcd
} // end fuction gcd
```

Comment: `I cant make the function work.` What is wrong with your program, please provide more details.

Comment: When I run it, it displays the incorrect information. It should display 10 with the data I input.

Comment: Your `greatestdivisor` function seems not to do much if you were shooting for a gcd algorithm, and the test condition within it should be `x < size` regardless.

Comment: @AdrianPxndx try your algorithm on paper first, e.g. with the values 18,9 your greatestdivisor function returns 18 which is not correct.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I did give a try to all methods. I use the array one because professor ask for an array at this point, but we will use vectors in the future and I appreciate the examples you gave me.Vectors seem easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues in your code, `try this` and figure out what you are doing wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int greatestdivisor(int b[], int size); /*Write prototype for gcd */

int main()
{
    int greatest;
    int max=1;
    int* a= new int[max]; //allocated on heap
    int n=0;

    cout<<"Input numbers: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Hit Enter key after each input and type any letter to finish"<<endl;

    while(cin>>a[n]){     //read into array
        n++;
        if(n>=max){
            max=n+1;   //increase size of array
            int* temp = new int[max];    //creates new bigger array

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                temp[i] = a[i];   //copy values to new array
            } //end for
            delete [] a;     //free old array memory
            a = temp;     //a points to new array
        } //end if

    } // end while
    cout<<endl;
    greatest = greatestdivisor(a, n);
    cout<<"The GCD of: "<<" is: "<<endl;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        cout<<setw(5)<<a[j]<<setw(10)<<greatest<<endl;
} // end main


int gcd(int a,int b)
{
    int t;
    while(a)
    {
        t = a;
        a = b%a;
        b = t;
    }
    return b;
}

// gcd finds greatest common divisor of array
int greatestdivisor(int b[], int size)
{
    int greatest =b[0];// current greatest common divisor, 1 is minimum

    for (int x=1; x<size; x++) {
        greatest = gcd(greatest, b[x]); // update greatest common divisor
    } // end for
    return greatest; //return gcd
} // end fuction gcd
```

Answer (score 2):

Your GCD algorithm is broken. It should be finding the GCD of each successive value in the array, starting with the first two entries. Repeated for all entries in the array, the final gcd will be common among all of them. And as mentioned in comment, your size in your (broken) gcd iteration algorithm is wrong as well; it should be strictly-less-than.

A much-stripped down version looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

static int gcd(const int b[], size_t size);

int main()
{
    int* a = nullptr, value=0;
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cout<<"Input numbers:\n";
    while(std::cin >> value)
    {
        int *temp = new int[n+1];
        std::copy(a, a+n, temp);
        delete [] a;
        a = temp;
        a[n++] = value;
    }

    std::cout<<"The GCD is " <<  gcd(a, n) << '\n';
    delete [] a;
}

static int gcd(const int b[], size_t size)
{
    int res = (size > 0 ? std::abs(b[0]) : 0);
    for (size_t x=1; x<size; ++x)
    {
        int n = std::abs(b[x]);
        while (n > 0)
        {
            auto tmp = res;
            res = n;
            n = tmp % n;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Output**

```
Input numbers: 
10
100
40
x
The GCD is 10
```

---

**Making The World a Better Place: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)**

Now that you can see how a manually managed dynamic array can work, I cannot stress enough how much simpler this can be by *not* doing it in the first place and rather simply using canned functionality from the standard library. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) will make short work of this task, and with that the code becomes monumentally less prone to errors. You get dynamic memory management from `std::vector`, and formatted input copying to EOF or non- `int` data using `std::istream_iterator`. In short, almost everything data-management-wise is handled for you.

Take a look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

static int gcd(const int b[], size_t size);

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Input numbers:\n";
    std::vector<int> a((std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)),
                        std::istream_iterator<int>());
    std::cout<<"The GCD is " <<  gcd(a.data(), a.size()) << '\n';
}

static int gcd(const int b[], size_t size)
{
    int res = (size > 0 ? std::abs(b[0]) : 0);
    for (size_t x=1; x<size; ++x)
    {
        int n = std::abs(b[x]);
        while (n > 0)
        {
            auto tmp = res;
            res = n;
            n = tmp % n;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

The output is the same as before. Best of luck

Comment: This is nice - I didn't know about istream iterators. +1

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is specified entirely in the way you have described, then it seems an `array` is not explicitly required.

As such, you can simplify to something like

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int greatestdivisor(std::vector<int> &ints);
int euclid(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> listOfInts;
    std::string line = "default";
    int tempInt=0;

    std::cout << "Description" << std::endl;

    while (line.length() != 0)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::stringstream temp(line);
    temp >> tempInt;
    listOfInts.push_back(tempInt);
    }
    listOfInts.pop_back(); // Remove the last entry, which is counted twice by this while loop :/

    for (int i=0; i< listOfInts.size(); i++)
    {
      std::cout<< listOfInts[i] << std::endl;
    }

    int gcd = greatestdivisor(listOfInts);
    std::cout << "gcd = " << gcd << std::endl;
}

int greatestdivisor(std::vector<int> &ints)
{
  int currentGCD = ints[0];
  while (ints.size() > 0)
  {
    int a = ints.back();
    ints.pop_back();
    currentGCD = euclid(a, currentGCD);
    std::cout <<  "currentGCD = " << currentGCD << std::endl;
  }
  return currentGCD;
}

int euclid(int a, int b)
{
  if (b == 0)
    return a;
  else
    return euclid(b, a % b);
}
```